# Topic Modeling: How to "find thoughts" STM function when topic model was made with a quanteda dfm object?

Tags: r, machine-learning, topic-modeling, quanteda

I am new to topic modeling, so I will do my best to describe the question I have. basically, I am wanting to visually inspect the documents that make up the topics in my topic model. I used the following code from package stm to build a topic model:

```
stm.35 <- stm(
  dfm, 
  K = 35,
  prevalence = NULL,
  content = NULL,
  data = NULL,
  init.type = c("LDA"),
  seed = 123, 
  emtol = 1e-05,
  verbose = TRUE,
  reportevery = 5,
  LDAbeta = TRUE,
  interactions = TRUE,
  ngroups = 1,
  model = NULL,
  gamma.prior = c("Pooled"),
  sigma.prior = 0,
  kappa.prior = c("L1"),coefficients.
  control = alpha (0.01)
)
```

The documents are social media comments on Reddit. When I try to use the "findThoughts" function, I get this:

```
 Topic 1:
```

I have read that the reason i can't view the topics is because i used a dfm from quanteda to build the stm. That being said, is there a work around for this? or should i try and build my model with an stm object, not a quanteda dfm? I would rather not do this, since I am finding greater success building the dfm with quanteda.

Thank you

Comment: You're not showing any code that would help with knowing how you called `findThoughts()`, but in essence, it will work fine, if you supply the corpus object as the `texts` argument. (In `sum::findThoughts()`, `text = NULL` really should not have the `= NULL`, since this argument should not be optional.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm encountering the same issue. I'm using

```
thoughts1 <- findThoughts(stmM_15_k42,texts = corp_media, n = 2, topics = 6)
```

But get the error message

```
Error in findThoughts(stmM_15_k42, texts = corp_media, n = 2, topics = 6) :
```

Number of provided texts and number of documents modeled do not match

I imagine the reason for this is that I trimmed and subset the quanteda corpus, even removing duplicates. So the DFM used for fitting the model is not the same as the corpus.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have the same issue as OP. But for your problem here's a solution, truncated for space limits. Long story short is that the preprocessing functions built into `stm` let you get either the names of the documents included in the final object (so you can subset your original documents to only equal those), or they also provide the names of *removed* documents. So either way of subsetting works.

Comment: Given a vector of documents named `docs`, converted into a corpus called `corpus`, I can subset a bunch of ways. This solution from the `stmPrinter` package works on corpus/df/vector objects, so would work on both the original 'docs' and 'corpus'

`docs_truncated <- docs[-c(as.integer(out$docs.removed))][-c(as.integer(out$docs.removed))]`

This alternative of my own doing only works on corpus objects
`docs_truncated <-corpus_subset(corpus, docname_ %in% names(out$documents)) `